# Connect OVRGearVrController to Scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, gearvrcontroller

It's should be simple but I can't find any proper tutorial/sample for this.

I imported the OVR package to my Unity scene,

and put the `OVRGearVrController` in the middle of it.

I can see the controller in my scene, but that's it.

How or where should I connect it to react to the real controller that it's in my hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import the latest OculusUtilities package to your project
2. Replace the default Camera with `OVRCameraRig`
3. Add `GearVrController` under the `RightHandAnchor`