# How to implement selection with GearVrController - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, samsung-mobile, oculus, gearvrcontroller

[So I figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44702058/1038702) how to add a GearVrController to a scene.

The controller follows the hand movements.

But how can I implement the selection part + a ray from the device to the scene?

I mean a ray that can select item, like the image below that taken from Oculus menus.

I'm looking for a build-in solution from Oculus if there is one. (I don't care about the menu itself, I'm trying to understand how to implement selection with the controller)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. For the `Ray` you could use a so called `LineRenderer` in `Unity`. Attach one to your controller and via script you can assign the [start and end point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html) (`SetPosition(int index, Vector3 position);` for indexes use 0 and 1 and the positions are the controller and the whatever you choose).
2. For your menu, you could use a [world based `Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html) that sits on top of the controller at all times. You can toggle it on a specific button pres from the controller

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a build in solution of GearVR. I have the feeling that there is one, and I'm missing it.

Comment: @David If you meant to say 'built-in' solutions for the `Oculus`, for the pointer I believe there are none, for your menu check out [this](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/0.4/concepts/mobile-unity-design/) document from the dev. forum. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a `build-in` solution. But I think you missed my point. I don't care about the menu in the image, it could be any simple button. I'm trying to understand how to implement selection with the controller

Comment: @David Quote: "how to implement selection with the controller" Answer: using a `LineRenderer` :)